# How to make my code do something different if an error occurs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My code currently requires user input to get an object from a JSON, but I want my code to send the user a different message if it encounters an error.

I've tried:

```
catch(err) {
message.channel.send('Incorrect data')
}
```

But that breaks my async block causing

```
const ricp = await fetch('http://ric.pikapools.com/api/stats').then(response => response.json());
```

To stop working.

Does anybody know of a way where I can make it do something when an error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
.catch(function(err) {
  message.channel.send('Incorrect data')
});
```

You can switch out the function with an arrow function too. Hope this helps :)